# Organizing package Python - importing modules that are used with the package

Tags: python, import, module, package, init

I'm writing a code and am trying to organize this, however I'm having some trouble.

I really would like to have a structure like:

```
/package
    /utils
      __init__.py
      func1.py
      func2.py
 __init__.py
 Main.py
```

Such I just have to do `import package`

So my `__init__.py` in Package contains:

`from package.main import mainfunction
import package.utils`.

and the `__init.py` in the utils folder contains:

`from package.utils.func1 import function1
from package.utils.func2 import function2`

So far so good, importing this gives that I'm able to run:

`package.mainfunction()`, `package.utils.function1()` and `package.utils.function2()`

However, where I get stuck is that my main function uses other modules like OpenCV and functions that are in the utils folder. I tried adding `import cv2` in the utils.__init_ file. But after trying to import package, it seems that the init file does not import cv2. Also, if my mainfunction() contains package.utils.function1() it does not seem to recognize it.

Am I going for a weird structure? Or what might be going wrong?

ps. I can work around the /utils folder, by just putting the `def function()` inside of my function in the Main.py. But I prefer to have them outside of it and that should be possible right?

Comment: Could you share the import statements you have in both the __init__ files?

Comment: @suicidalteddy, I added it in the description. I get every function to load, but I cant use package.utils.function1() or any other module such as cv2 in my main script. That's where I'm stuck..

Comment: Unless you have some functional logic inside your init files, you need not import anything in them. Why not import cv2 in your main.py?

Comment: It seems that if I add `from package.utils.func1 import function1` in my main.py it does not import it (unless I put the import inside of the `def function():` structure). I can run the script itself instead of the function, but I would like to be able to import the function such that I can run it in python by giving it some variables (`package.mainfunction(x,y,z)`

Comment: Ok, I got it to work! Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having trouble with this, this is how I got it to work now:

```
/package
     /utils
         __init__.py    -->  from package.utils.func1 import function1
                             from package.utils.func2 import function2
         func1.py
         func2.py

   __init__.py          -->  from package.main import mainscript

   main.py              -->  import package.utils
                             import cv2
```

Now it imports all with use of `import package`

Make sure that using function1 and function2 in the main.py is like `package.utils.function1()`